# Starting OpenCPU single user on windows

Tags: windows, opencpu

When I try and load the openCpu library in Rstudio and RGui on Windows server 2008 R2, SP1 I get the message:

"The program can't start because MSVCR90.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem."

The script then gives the following messages in console:

"Intiating OpenCPU server ...
Using config: C:/users/[username]/documents/.opencpu.conf
Waiting for server to respond...
Server unresponsive; restarting.
OpenCPU stopped.
Using config: C:/users/[username]/documents/.opencpu.conf"

It will keep repeating this until force stopped. The server, however, is running.

I am sure that MSVCR90.dll is neither missing nor damaged. I have uninstalled and re-installed r, rstudio, and all packages.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is likely a problem in one of the dependencies. Can you load `httpuv`, `jsonlite`, `httr` and `devtools` and `openssl`?

Comment: The problem has resurfaced. I am using:

opencpu 1.6.1
httpuv 1.3.3
jsonlite 1.2
httr 1.2.1
devtools 1.12.0
openssl 0.9.6